# python create a list of imported modules

Tags: python-3.x

```html
from spacy.symbols import amod, prep, nsubj, csubj, dobj, iobj, acomp, attr
from spacy.symbols import NN, NNS, JJ, JJS, JJR, conj

MR = [amod, prep, nsubj, csubj, dobj, iobj, acomp, attr]
nn = [NN, NNS]
jj = [JJ, JJS, JJR]
CONJ = [conj]
target = set()
opinion_word = ['great']
for each_sent in list(doc.sents):
    for word in each_sent:
        if word in opinion_word and word.dep in MR and word.head.pos in nn:
            target.add(word.head)
```

Hello
I know this question has been posted but I didn’t find a suitable answer for my problem.
I would like to subset all the modules imported to use them in if statement as shown in my code. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

hi i found out the trick for my problem. 
I just had to import each attribute from the module as "a variable"

> from spacy.symbols import amod as a, prep as b, nsubj as c, acomp as d ...

and then i can create the list of the attribute by using the variables

> MR = [a, b, c, d]

and use my MR in my if statement.